# Connect Phantom Wallet on Page Load with solana-wallet-adaper

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, phantom-wallet

I am using @solana/wallet-adapter with Next js
And on a particular wallet, I need the autoConnect on page load.
I would've gone with `window.solana.connect()` but it doesn't detect when the user switches wallet

Comment: If I answered your question please mark this as answered, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `autoConnect` in your `<WalletProvider .. >`

```
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    <WalletMultiButton />
                    <WalletDisconnectButton />
                    { /* Your app's components go here, nested within the context providers. */ }
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
```

https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md

Comment: oh but this would affect the whole site since this is in the app.js
I was thinking if I could use it on individual pages. Because I need it on one page only

Comment: you can set set autoConnect based on what page you are on. e.g. `somepage ? autoConnect : None` (just an abstract example)